# What are the ways available in iOS to communicate between one to many devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, apple-push-notifications

I want to know the different options which are available in iOS to communicate between one to many devices.

For example, one iPhone or iPad acts as server and sends instructions to more than 100 iPads or iPhones.

Can I get some ideas or suggestions on this?

Comment: Push, e-mail, carrier pigeon, sockets, mdnsresponder. Are you on a local network, Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TCP or UDP over a local WLAN.
It is quite easy. To discover the "Server"-device create a Bonjour Service on this device and search for the service with the client-devices

You can then retrieve the IP Address of the device and start communication.
This is the fastest and easiest solution. It has just one requirement, all Devices need to be in the same WLAN.

The additional bonus is that this layout is accessible for all devices having WLAN. So also Android, computers and all the other stuff available.

An optional way would be to do this over a dedicated server backend. 
And every device keeps a opened stream to this server to get realtime updates.
Then you don't have the requirement that every device needs to be in the same WLAN. It could also access the Server via mobile network or whatever.

Bluetooth is no option because there are too many devices you want to handle.